# Parse a block where each line starts with a specific symbol

Tags: parsing, yacc, lalr

I need to parse a block of code which looks like this:

```
* Block
| Line 1
| Line 2
| ...
```

It is easy to do:

```
block : head lines;
head  : '*' line;
lines : lines '|' line
      | '|' line
      ;
```

Now I wonder, how can I add nested blocks, e.g.:

```
* Block
| Line 1
| * Subblock
| | Line 1.1
| | ...
| Line 2
| ...
```

Can this be expressed as a `LALR` grammar?

I can, of course, parse the top-level blocks and than run my parser again  to deal with each of these top-level blocks. However, I'm just learning this topic so it's interesting for me to avoid such approach.

Comment: The example you present has a unclear endOfBlock (the grammar will become strange because of the "| | " staff. Something with a eofBlock token, like *Block{
  |Line 1
  *SubBlock{
     | line 1.1
     | line 1.2
  }
  |Line 2
  |...
} would be much easier...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nested-block language is not context-free [Note 2], so it cannot be parsed with an LALR(k) parser.

However, nested parenthesis languages are, of course, context-free and it is relatively easy to transform the input into a parenthetic form by replacing the initial <kbd>|</kbd> sequences in the lexical scanner. The transformation is simple:

- when the initial sequence of <kbd>|</kbd>s is longer than the previous line, insert an `BEGIN_BLOCK`. (The initial sequence must be exactly one <kbd>|</kbd> longer; otherwise it is presumably a syntax error.)
- when the initial sequence of <kbd>|</kbd>s, is shorter then the previous line, enough `END_BLOCK`s are inserted to bring the expected length to the correct value.
- The <kbd>|</kbd>s themselves are not passed through to the parser.

This is very similar to the `INDENT`/`DEDENT` strategy used to parse layout-aware languages like Python an Haskell. The main difference is that here we don't need a stack of indent levels.

Once that transformation is finished, the grammar will look something like:

```
content: /* empty */
       | content line
       | content block
block  : head BEGIN_BLOCK content END_BLOCK
       | head
head   : '*' line
```

A rough outline of a flex implementation would be something like this: (see Note 1, below).

```
%x INDENT CONTENT
%%
  static int depth = 0, new_depth = 0;
  /* Handle pending END_BLOCKs */
  send_end:
    if (new_depth < depth) {
      --depth;
      return END_BLOCK;
  }
^"|"[[:blank:]]*   { new_depth = 1; BEGIN(INDENT); }
^.                 { new_depth = 0; yyless(0); BEGIN(CONTENT);
                     goto send_end; }
^\n                /* Ignore blank lines */
<INDENT>{
  "|"[[:blank:]]*  ++new_depth;
  .                { yyless(0); BEGIN(CONTENT);
                     if (new_depth > depth) {
                       ++depth;
                       if (new_depth > depth) { /* Report syntax error */ }
                       return BEGIN_BLOCK;
                     } else goto send_end;
                   }
  \n               BEGIN(INITIAL); /* Maybe you care about this blank line? */
}
  /* Put whatever you use here to lexically scan the lines */
<CONTENT>{
  \n               BEGIN(INITIAL);
}
```

#### Notes:

1. Not everyone will be happy with the `goto` but it saves some code-duplication. The fact that the state variable (`depth` and `new_depth`) are local `static` variables makes the lexer non-reentrant and non-restartable (after an error). That's only useful for toy code; for anything real, you should make the lexical scanner re-entrant and put the state variables into the `extra` data structure.
2. The terms "context-free" and "context-sensitive" are technical descriptions of grammars, and are therefore a bit misleading. Intuitions based on what the words seem to mean are often wrong. One very common source of context-sensitivity is a language where validity depends on two different derivations of the same non-terminal producing the same token sequence. (Assuming the non-terminal could derive more than one token sequence; otherwise, the non-terminal could be eliminated.)

   There are lots of examples of such context-sensitivity in normal programming languages; usually, the grammar will allow these constructs and the check will be performed later in some semantic analysis phase. These include the requirement that an identifier be declared (two derivations of `IDENTIFIER` produce the same string) or the requirement that a function be called with the correct number of parameters (here, it is only necessary that the length of the derivations of the non-terminals match, but that is sufficient to trigger context-sensitivity).

   In this case, the requirement is that two instances of what might be called `bar-prefix` in consecutive lines produce the same string of <kbd>|</kbd>s. In this case, since the effect is really syntactic, deferring to a later semantic analysis defeats the point of parsing. Whether the other examples of context-sensitivity are "syntactic" or "semantic" is a debate which produces a surprising amount of heat without casting much light on the discussion.

Comment: Cool! (often in my lexers i include a queue of toBeReturned tokens) +1

Comment: Sorry, is `extra` data structure a flex provided variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you write an explicit end-of-block token, things become clearer:

```
*Block{
  |Line 1
  *SubBlock{
     | line 1.1
     | line 1.2
  }
  |Line 2
  |...
}
```

and grammar becomes:

```
block : '*' ID '{' lines '}'
lines : lines  '|' line
      | lines  block
      |
```

Comment: If you were to follow this approach, you would  have a completely different language :) And the `*` and `|` symbols wouldn't be necessary at all, since the `{` and `}` would be sufficient.

Comment: @rici, i know; that is why i say this a comment (a sintax language alternative discussing comment    )