# How can Jflex return multiple terminals at once

Tags: compilation, jflex

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42434603/how-can-flex-return-multiple-terminals-at-one-time) question about Flex gives an example of a nonblock do-loop in fortran:

```
DO 20 I=1, N      ! line 1
DO 20 J=1, N      ! line 2
    ! more codes
20  CONTINUE      ! line 4
```

As the question elaborates, on line 4 the label 20 serves as the end of both the inner and outer `DO` loop. Ideally a Jflex program parsing this will output two `ENDDO` terminals when it sees the last 20.

I've tried the method detailed in the answer to the above function, but Jflex doesn't appear to insert code after the `%%` sign into the `yylex` function like Flex does according to that answer.

How can something like this be implemented in Jflex? More generally, how can Jflex return two terminals from one action?