# How to replace a lexer token with two new tokens?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

In XML an empty element can be represented in either of these ways:

```
<foo></foo>
<foo/>
```

If the input contains the latter, then I want to tokenize it like the former.

That is, if the input is `<foo/>` then I want the lexer to generate this sequence of `(token kind, token value)` pairs:

```
('<', '<')
("foo", STAG)
('>', '>')
("</foo>", ETAG)
```

I tried this (where `<START_TAG>` is an exclusive state and `st` is a global variable holding the element name, which is `"foo"` in this example):

```
<START_TAG>{
   "/>"    { yytext = ">";
             return(">");
             yytext = strcat(strcat("<", st), ">");
             yyval.strval = strdup(yytext);
             yy_pop_state();
             return(ETAG); 
           }
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Essentially I want the lexer to replace this token `"/>"` with these two tokens: `">"` and `"</foo>"`. How do I do that?

Comment: Either you need to implement a token queue, or you need to use bison's push-parser interface. I prefer the push-parser but both are possible.

Comment: Why? The parser should be able to cope with both forms.

Comment: Longer answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42434603/how-can-flex-return-multiple-terminals-at-one-time/42444111

Comment: Also, I basically agree with @user207421. But it's good to know how to fabricate multiple tokens from a scanner action.

Comment: That transformation requires that the algorithm understands the syntax or at least some subset of it. Syntax is not lexer's job; it doesn't have the right tools to interpret it. Parser is designed for syntax and it should be used to handle it. (Of course, you could try some ugly hacks but I doubt it will end well in the long run.)

Answer (score 0):

After the returning statement `return(">");` you don't execute anything else.

Also, changing the internal variable `yytext` with `yytext = ">";` is never a good idea. First `strdup(yytext)` and then change anything you need in the new pointer.